# Should we run a community survey/census?

Tags: discussion

The idea was raised in chat of running our own community survey/census.

Do you think this would be a good idea? What sort of questions would be good to include?

Comment: How would this information be helpful?

Comment: @4castle Probably largely for curiosity. Perhaps as something to correct mispresentations (I occasionally see new people say something like the site is all made up of Catholics or all made up of Evangelicals, neither of which is true)

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to know the ratio of people who come here because they use StackOverflow and stay for the Christianity vs the ratio of people who came here because of google searches.  And if you are a Christian programmer type, something about your comfort level as a Christian in your professional life.

Comment: Some people came from other sites in the network. My first site was Linguistics. Though I think I registered at both on the same day.

Answer (score 5):

Some basic demographic questions like country of residence and current church denomination attended (if any).

For the Christian members, at what stage of life they became a Christian.

Personal devotional metrics: how frequently you attend church, read the Bible, pray, etc

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be interesting to also see some beliefs and how they may differ within the same denominations. This is pretty broad but it might be interesting to put some in.

- trinity (God, Jesus, and Holy Ghost are one)
- Nontrinitarianism  (God, Jesus, and Holy Ghost are separate beings)
- is the bible only doctrine
- can I receive personal answers to prayers
- etc

Or even ask on scale of 1 to 10 how well you think you know other denomination. This could be hard to do from a survey point of view as there are thousands but I feel like you could limit it to the top 10 most common or something.

1. Catholicism
2. Protestanism (Baptist, Lutheranism, Methodist, Presbyterianism)
3. Modern Protestanism (Pentecostalism, Evangelism)
4. Eastern Orthodoxy
5. Anglicism
6. Non-trinitarian Restorationism (Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints, Jehovah's Witnesses)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some questions on theology and politics:

To what extent do you think the church should be involved in politics

Do you approach politics as a single issue voter

If you are a Christian would you ever vote for a non Christian politician

Other ideas?

Comment: I feel political questions could cause problems; it would potentially be easy for troublemakers outside this site to point to one and say "Look, Christians believe X", when in fact this group contains a wide variety of beliefs, including atheists.

Comment: NO! Please keep the politics out of this site. It is everywhere else. Just **NO!**